# Linear search in a array is returning unexpected results

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I need to develop a linear search algorithm that tests whether the array contains testVal

this is what I wrote

```
bool Contains(int a[], int arraySize, int testVal)
{

        bool contains = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
        {
            if (a[i] == testVal)
            {
                contains = true;
                std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            }
            else if (a[i] != testVal)
            {
                contains = false;
                std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return contains; }
```

When it debugs it prints correctly, but it also prints 19 "false". I guess it has something to do with the array size being 20. I don't how to fix it to only print once without the 19 "false". Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Think about how to stop the loop when you find the value.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to put the following condition in your `for` loop:

```
bool contains = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize && !contains; ++i)
```

The reason why this works without changing anything else in your code is that `contains` is set to `true` when the value is found.

Thus on the next iteration (if you haven't reached the end of the array already) the loop's condition `i < arraySize && !contains` will be `false`, thus terminating the loop.

Another way to look at it is if the `!` is confusing, the following lines do the same thing:

```
bool contains = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize && (contains == false); ++i)
```

The loop only continues if `i < arraySize` and the `contains` value is `false`.  Since you set `contains` to `true` when you find the value, the `for` loop terminates on the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you only need to change the value of `contains` when it is found, and set `false` as the default, that is so that when searching through the end of the array, and still not found, the result would be `false`

if it is found, set `contain` to `true` and `break` out of the loop, because it is already found, no need for further testing

and change `++i` to `i++`, the difference is `++i` is added before the code in the nest executed, so that if you use `arraySize` of 10, your loop would be 1 to 9, that is 9 times, compared to `i++`, the `i` is added after the nest executed, so with the same `arraySize`, your loop would be 0 to 9, that is 10 times

```
bool Contains(int a[], int arraySize, int testVal)
{
    bool contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == testVal)
        {
            contains = true;
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return contains; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return once you find that it contains testVal or you can break the for loop. Returning is better and is done in the code below with minimal change.

```
bool Contains(int a[], int arraySize, int testVal)
{

    bool contains = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] == testVal)
        {
            contains = true;
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
            return contains;
        }
        else if (a[i] != testVal)
        {
            contains = false;
            std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return contains; }
```

You can also just update contains when you find the match as in below code. In this code, you may not have to use return inside for loop. But if you do that your code will be faster in the sense that it won't wait for terminating the loop.

```
bool Contains(int a[], int arraySize, int testVal)
{

    bool contains = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] == testVal)
        {
            contains = true;
            std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return contains; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Contains(int a[], int arraySize, int testVal)
{   


bool contains = false;
for (int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
{
    if (a[i] == testVal)
    {
        contains = true;
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
        return contains;
    }
}
return contains; }
```

You must use **i++** instead of **++i** and you must use return statement in the **if** block so that if the testval is found than no further testing is carried out.